# VSLookup on sheet1 & Input data on sheet2

Tags: excel, if-statement

Our daily billing is done in Excel as follows:

Cell-F(name)Cell-G(hours)Cell-H(billing rate)Cell-I(description)Cell-J(total)

```
Joe Customer   1  Office    Install Windows updates    $85
```

I have a series of IF statements in Cell-J that look at the hours in cell-G and billing rate in Cell-H to set the billing rate value.

I would like to add a sheet with my customer names and use VSLOOKUP to grab the customer name and billing rate and input it automatically. Hopefully in conjunction with the IF statements.

I want to enter "Joe Customer" in Cell-F and have it set the billing rate in Cell-H then have the IF statement set the hourly rate.

[Billing Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SuZI.png)[image]

[Customer Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNWqB.png)[image]

Comment: As you are doing two conjuctive lookups INDEX/MATCH in array form is best.  Or slide your data over one column and concatenate the name and Billing rate into one column in your lookup table, then you can use VLOOKUP.

Comment: VSLOOKUP is not a native worksheet function. Kindly add the code for this UDF to your question.

Answer (score 0):

For column H starting in row 2:

```
=vlookup(F2,Customers!$A$1:$C$500,2,FALSE)
```

For column J, starting in row 2

```
=vlookup(F2,Customers!$A$1:$C$500,3,FALSE)
```

Copy down.